# Jetpack Compose Constraint Layout. Constraint in preview are shifted

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout

Demonstration of the problem -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjjL3.png
In the preview, when using Constraint Layout, the constraints in the preview window are indicated with an offset. How can this be fixed?
At the same time, the project itself compiles and works fine, the restrictions also work fine. It's not a big problem, but it looks annoying.

I thought these were problems in IntelliJ IDEA, I work in it, but in Android Studio the problem does not disappear.